# using decltype in template arguments of initialization of base class fails to compile

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

See the code below. Why is parenthesis needed? Is it defined by standard?

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fbfPPGWc1

```cpp
template<int I>
struct Base {};

template<int I>
struct Derived: Base<I>
{
  // ERROR
  Derived(int): Base<decltype(0){I}>() {}

  // OK (Note the parenthesis)
  Derived(char): Base<(decltype(0){I})>() {}

  // OK
  Base<decltype(0){I}> x = Base<decltype(0){I}>();
};

int main() {
}
```

Comment: i'll go for an obscure compiler bug

Comment: @M.M Hmm, it fails on g++, msvc, and clang. If it is a bug, they all managed to get it wrong in exactly the same way.

Comment: It is [_really_](https://twitter.com/zygoloid/status/1491966222736322560) hard to figure out where a mem-initializer-id ends when you are dealing with what amounts to arbitrary token soup (that can refer to later-declared members).

Comment: Interestingly, moving the constructor definition out of the class allows it to compile on g++ and clang, but msvc still gives the same error. `template<int I>
Derived<I>::Derived(int) : Base<decltype(0){I}>() {}`

Comment: To be quite honest, that twitter thread is the most cursed thing I've ever come across in C++.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you. I think that your link is the source of this question(I got it from another people).